# How efficient is a Solr / Lucene on huge sorted query with limit clause

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search

I have a shard with nearly 2G documents.
I'm trying to understand how efficient will be a query which its result set include most of the documents but it includes sorting and limit.
In SQL database the database can use the sorting and limit clause to check only a very small amount of rows based on the sorted field index.
Do Lucene / Solr do the same?

```
Query example: select * sort by date limit 50
```

Comment: Solr/Lucent uses inverted index. It does not have sort information. SQL has b-tree, which is sorted (exact match) index. Hence for ordered queries SQL is the DB of choice.

Answer (score 1):

Please keep in mind, that solr/lucene is focused on fulltext-search.

So your SQL query is not really an "search" (in the meaning of solars fulltext.search). It's more like extracting data form an database with sorting and limit.

See an SQL database as something like an excel-sheet, where you have direct excess to the columns of each row.

No go into the solr point of view, which is an index, like an table of content from an book.

So if you search for all (*), order by date (which is possible in solr), solr (probably) will go trough the whole index, collecting time information in order to sort that and cuts the output after 50 documents.

This will work in solr very well but selecting this from a database will be more efficiently, I think. Because delivering (and storing) data is exactly what it (a database) was designed for.

There are different kind of caches and mechanism, in solr, which are focused on searching for terms in fields. The solr focus is not so much in onyl delivering data.

If you really (only) need to return documents, but without searching for, so an SQL databases will probably work more efficiency than solr.

But: If you start searching insight the "rows" for terms, so solr/lucene is the way to chose.

Answer (score 0):

Similar but different.

Sorting in Solr is discussed here:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Common+Query+Parameters#CommonQueryParameters-ThesortParameter

Limit the number of rows:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Common+Query+Parameters#CommonQueryParameters-TherowsParameter

Date fields are discussed here:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Working+with+Dates

Solr's TrieDateField uses a 64-bit integer (not a string) to hold a date, representing milliseconds since January 1, 1970.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Working+with+Dates?focusedCommentId=61338556#comment-61338556

You will query Solr, specifying a sort on a field of type TrieDateField. Solr will order results by that sort, and the number of documents in the response is based on the 'rows' parameter.  Efficiency is comparable to that of a SQL DB. Try it and see.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm looking for information on how the query is executed in such scenario which isn't answered in your answer. @rleir

Comment: The title says 'how efficient'. Maybe you could edit it? @Avner Levy